# Auto Complete Not Working. in VS C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm working on my dataGridView and I'm trying to make one of my cell to be auto Complete, but its not working.

C# code:

```
private void dataGridRequest_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox prodCode = e.Control as TextBox;
    if (prodCode != null)
    {
        prodCode.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        prodCode.AutoCompleteCustomSource = itemList;
        prodCode.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check 2 things:

1. Check if `itemList` is empty
2. Disable the multiline option in the textbox ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource.aspx) MSDN mentions it doesn't work on multiline TextBox Controls)

Comment: I already check my itemList and its not empty.
and I'm not using any multiline.

Comment: What about the `WrapMode` property of your data grid view? If it's set to true, AutoCompleteMode won't work.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.wrapmode%28v=vs.90%29

Comment: I can't find the WrapMode in my property,.

Comment: I tried making my wrapmode into false. but still nothing came out my textbox

Comment: Sorry no idea then :(